# Model doesn't update the database

Tags: c#, sql, ado.net

For some reason the method `dbase.SaveChanges()` can't update the database because `roomid` should be null.
But the debugger does say that `room1.id` is set to 2?

Can somebody please help me with this ?

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Room room1 = new Room();
    room1.Id = 2;
    dbase.AddToRoom(room1);
    dbase.SaveChanges();
}
```

Comment: but... you __are__ setting it to 2...

Comment: Maybe Id is identity column?

Comment: you are calling a Insert Method and trying to update. You should search for the entity and set new values. After that just call SaveChanges() method.

Comment: thanks guys allready found the solution i had to update my entity model because i changed the database...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i'm not sure this is actually ADO.NET, it seems more like entity framework or linq to SQL.

It's also not quite clear what you're trying to do.
If you are trying to add a new Room to the database, i would advise setting some properties, otherwise you are just inserting an empty room.

```
var room1 = new Room();
room1.RoomNumber = 4;
room1.Available = true;
//...
dbase.AddToRoom(room1);
dbase.SaveChanges();
```

If this is what you are trying to do, then you do not need to specify the ID for the room (if the ID column is set to auto-increment that is.)

if you are trying to *update* a room instead of *inserting* a new one you can do something like this:

```
var roomToUpdate = dbase.Rooms.Where(x => x.id == id).FirstOrDefault();
roomToUpdate.Property ="something";
//...
dbase.Update(roomToUpdate)
dbase.SaveChanges();
```

Again, its not entirely clear what exactly you are trying to do so if i'm wrong, please elaborate a little more.